# JS find a dynamic number of averages based on value in adjacent column

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic, average

new to coding and trying to solve this. I have an HTML table of data with these column headings:

Continent, Country, City, Average Temperature

The table data is quite long, with many countries—and multiple entries for each country (i.e. different cities). **I want to calculate the average temperature for EACH country**—i.e. sum the Average Temperature column for all entries with the same Country, then divide by that number of entries.

**My goal is to end up with two arrays** that can be plugged into a chart with an X-Axis of 'Country' and Y-Axis of 'Avg Temp'.

I believe the following code would work for some of it, but I would have to copy and paste this for every single country (there are hundreds of countries).

```
//read the data from the HTML table
   var data = document.getElementById("myTable");

//find array values that match a country and push to new array, then convert array to integer
          var canada= [];
          var j = 0;
          for (j; j < data.rows.length; j++) {
             if ( data.rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML.indexOf("Canada") >= 0) 
                 canada.push(data.rows[j].cells[3].innerHTML);
           {

//sum the array for a country, find average, and push to a new array to plug into a chart
            function getSum(total, num) {
               return total + num;
               }
            myChartData.push(canada.reduce(getSum,0)/canada.length);
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to create an array of all unique country values from the Country column, and then somehow execute the above code for each value in this array. Any thoughts? Or better ways to do this?

Comment: Do u know all the countries that are in the list ? You could create a list of countries then and iterate through it fro each value. Then you could get the average of each.

Comment: please reply, its been over 45 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oka so there are two solutions that I found here, one which is a simple nested loop and the other a slightly more dynamic approach. assuming the rest of ur code works it should look like this.

1. Nested Loop. Create a List of all possible countries and then u can run the function for the individual country. O(n^2)

   ```
   //create a list of countries 
   const countries = ["Canada", "India", "Austrailia"]; 

   for (const element of countries){
    console.log(element);

    var temperatures = [] 
    for (j = 0 ; j < data.rows.length; j++){
        if (data.rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML.indexOf(element) >= 0) 
            temperatures.push(data.rows[j].cells[3].innerHTML);
    }    
    //assuming this was an array defined before. you can plot countries to myChartData
    myChartData.push(temperatures.reduce(getSum,0)/temperatures.length); 
   }
   ```
2. Using a Map dynamically. (O)(n) + tiny bit more

   ```
    //list of countries to simulate data (country, temp)
    const data = [["Canada",12], ["India",10], ["Austrailia",20],
                ["Canada",0],["Canada",18],["India",10]]; 

    let countryTemp = new Map(); 
    for (const element of data){
    //element[1] is data.rows[j].cells[3].innerHTML) or temp
    //element[0] is data.rows[j].cells[1].innerHTML) or country
        var temp = []; 
        //if exists collect list 
        if(countryTemp.has(element[0])) 
            temp = countryTemp.get(element[0])
        //append to list of tmepratures 
        temp.push(element[1]);       
        countryTemp.set(element[0],temp); 
    }


     //u can plot country list to avg temp list. 
    var countryList = []; 
    var avgTemperaturelist =[]; 
    for(const val of countryTemp){
         countryList.push(val[0]); 
         avgTemperaturelist.push(val[1].reduce(getSum,0)/val[1].length); 
    }
   ```

hint: u can make this even faster by using (sum and len(aunto-increment) in the map instead of a list i just used ur array logic

Comment: Thank you! And sorry for the delay (didn't realize stackoverflow moved this fast :D).

Your first example worked for me. I'm still polishing the output I want for the chart, but I am able to get the average temperature for each country in an array now with your code.